# Modifying the icon on the project node in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

I am new to Visual Studio and I would like to know how to modify the icon on the project node in a csproj.
I would like to create a c# project but would like to modify the default c# icon it shows.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean this icon(CSProjectNode):

[image]

To my knowledge, it is not possible to modify the default icon of project node in a project file(.xxproj file).

Before, I supposed the default used icons might be stored in one certain folder of VS, but I checked the related folders, there were some of other icons, and `.png` files but for CSProjectNode icon, I didn't find it.

Perhaps it is possible to change the icon by using codes to create a VS extension, but it's my guess and for options or project files(.xxproj file), there is no way to modify the default icon, at least for CSProjectNode.

But if you mean other icons, for example [application icon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2019#list-of-common-properties-and-parameters), it is possible to change. You can try to use

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ApplicationIcon>XXXX</ApplicationIcon>
</PropertyGroup>
```

================================================================
**Update:**

In Extensions > Customize menu… > Commands > Toolbar: > Standard | Debug Target, you can delete any command you want to remove. Just select it and Delete. Or you can delete more specific, such as:

Extensions > Customize menu… > Commands > Toolbar: > Standard | Debug Target | Web Browser > select Web Browser > click Delete > select `Select Web Browsers…` > click Delete. And Web Browser (Google Chrome) with be removed.

Extensions > Customize menu… > Commands > Toolbar: > Standard | Debug Target | Script Debugging > select `Enable` > Delete > select `Disable` > Delete. And Script Debugging will be removed.

Here, I deleted all the other commands and left Start Debug Target only, and you can see that other options are removed.

[image]

[image]

Of course, I may say, other commands are also useful, so you need to consider and decide whether you really need to remove them.

One more thing, since your project is Web project, the icon should be the web project related icon by default, there is no need to change the SDK to change the icon.

Comment: Yes i am talking about same icon, if you can share how i can do this from extension will be a great help. I am looking to something similar to android project which has mobile icon. Thanks

Comment: Developing an extension is not that easy, using existing extension will be easier, I checked the [Marketplace for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=VS&category=All%20categories&vsVersion=&sortBy=Installs) but didn’t find any extension which may meet your requirement. Is this icon really important for you to modify? Normally, it’s just a symbol which tells you that this is a C# project when you developing in VS.

Comment: Yes, i am able to change this to web (as the project is web project) bu changing sdk to microsoft.net.sdk.web. i am getting web icon instead of c#. Bit now tge problem is i get "select browser" option in debugger dropdown and few other which i want to get remove. Do you have any idea how to remove those option from debug button drop down in case csproj has microsoft.net.sdk.web as sdk. Thanks

Comment: Yes, this can be down, I have updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: Thank you... but how same can be done programmatically?

Comment: I know it is possible to [add or extend commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/extending-menus-and-commands?view=vs-2019)/menus… but for removing/turning off default Visual Studio feature programmatically seems not possible.